When a button is clicked, it creates a channel (ticket bot)
when i run my code:
if(!interaction.isButton() || interaction.customId !== 'ticketCreate') return;
        guild.channels.create({
            name: "test",
            type: ChannelType.GuildText,
        });

everything is fine, when i click the button thougj, nothing happens. anyone know why?
I tried putting this in my events folder and index.js file. I thought it would create a channel but nothing happend.

Show the full code, in which specific place you use this fragment?

Hey! i got this problem fixed, i dont know how to close it but ill figure it out.
